# Laravel notification email change title

Tags: laravel, notifications

I`m trying to send email notification.
When my emails sent the title is 'Example'.
How can i change the title by toMail() method of Notification class.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting($this->notifMessage['subject'])
        ->line($this->notifMessage['description']);
}
```

my code is here.

Thank you! Best regards.

Comment: ah. i found the solution. just change the config/mail.php 'from' attribute.

Comment: There's also an alternative approach. It all depends on whether you just want 'mail.from.name' to display or the actual senders name

Comment: ok. i`ll try it. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the config/mail.php 'from' field to match your need, however i would advice against doing so, im not saying this is the case but lets imagine you have two different senders, changing the config only allows one sender per website.
So the easy solution is to override the 'from' fields in the toMail() function itself, this way you can have as many senders as you want.

Just add

```
->from('some_adress','some_name')
```

to your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can easaly do:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        // other options
        ->from("An amazing sender")
        ->subject("Amazing email's subject");
}
```